# Showing that if $G$ is a solvable finite primitive group and $M$ is a core-free maximal subgroup of $G$, then $O_p(M)=1$ where $p$ divides $|Soc(G)|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups, socle

I’m trying to show that if $G$ is a solvable finite primitive group and $M$ is a core-free maximal subgroup of $G$, then $O_p(M)=1$ where $p$ divides $|Soc(G)|$ ($Soc(G)$ is the socle of $G$).

I know that a minimal normal subgroup $N$ of a solvable group will be elementary abelian, and then, if $G$ is a primitive group, it can be shown that $C_G(N)=N$. I also know that for a solvable group $G$, if $N$ is a minimal normal group of $G$ such that $C_G(N)=N$, then there is some prime $p$ such that $F(G)=N=O_p(G)$, where $F(G)$ is the Fitting subgroup of $G$, $N$ is complemented in $G$ by a maximal core-free subgroup $M$ and there exists a unique conjugacy class of such maximal subgroups in $G$.

I guess I could now use the definition of the Fitting subgroup as the direct product of $p$-cores for all the primes $p$ that divide the order of $G$ and try to conclude from there... I’ve also read [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/irredsol/htm/CHAP005.htm) that for this kind of group, the minimal normal subgroup $N$ will be unique and the socle will then coincide with $N$ (and then $Soc(G)=p^n$). I’m not sure how to show this, though.

Am I on the right track? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: So you have $G = NM$ with $N \cap M = 1$ and $N=F(G)$. That immediately implies $O_p(M)=1$ since $O_p(M) \le O_p(G) \le F(G) = N$.

Comment: Note also that the reason that $N$ is the unique minimal normal suibgroup of $G$ is that if there another one $K$, then we would have $K \cap N = 1$, so $K \le C_G(N)$, but we know that $C_G(N)=N$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you, if you make these comments into an answer I’ll accept it.

Comment: @DerekHolt Just one doubt: it isn’t immediately obvious to me that $O_p(M) \leq O_p(G)$ when $M \leq G$.

Comment: $G=NM$ implies that $NO_p(M)$ is a normal $p$-subgroup of $G$.